# Initializing an adjacency matrix in c++

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-matrix

I'm working on graph implementations in C++ and came across an implementation for an adjacency matrix that mostly made sense to me. The implementation uses an "init" function to initialize the matrix:

```
void init(int n) {

    numVertex = 0;
    numEdge = 0;

    mark = new int[n]; //initialize mark array
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++) {
        mark[i] = 0;
    }

    matrix = (int**) new int*[numVertex]; //make matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[numVertex];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++) { //mark all matrix cells as false
        for (int j = 0; j < numVertex; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The line I'm confused about is:

```
 matrix = (int**) new int*[numVertex]; //make matrix
```

What does the `(int**)` aspect do? Why would I choose to use this instead of `matrix = new int**[numVertex];`?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(int**)value` is a C-style cast operation.

Notes:

- Don't use those in C++, it tends to cause or hide problems, like mismatches between right and left side of an assignment.
- The code is relatively low quality, proper C++ would rather use `std::vector`.
- The code is also not complete, so little can be said with certainty about how it functions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `matrix = new int**[numVertex];` as mentioned by you would create (for this example) a 3D array, because you'd have `numVertex` entries of `int**`.

The `(int**)` cast does not accomplish much, if anything at all, because if `matrix` is of type `int**`, there is no need for the cast (you get back an `int**` already from the `new`).

Answer (score 0):

If column dimension is fixed, you can use vector of array there.
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgDdMyIsQ3YOABgCCchUpWZ1WpsWJMAnkdMWu8xcrUbNeVEECYkwmAFs3c0tvGzt/VDDWPAAHSItzAkww5OZMvwJnZMwWcNsAFVJVBQJVNAY0kUEFYFViVAB3AH1M7IY7ABFVIPQQEAcnVy0KurdZPiiMrJymPK0CopKw8srq2tQGSp7lzLj14tLyFgIjVTPN2wBVAdaO7qX62WNzRubVRII3r1nsNRrp9CQ/A8/NN9rNjHN3O5dokFBAAJSIgDs8zMqjxexYQUwAA9ksQqldVCwRGEAGqYYiZYnPWQmDQ4/EEomk8m7alhXDAWwaQas9nuTloQlMskUmr8zT7Z78%2BmMkni8ycvk0gBKHWVNMFmA1uPxPzYLy6NRFlsBOT81UqCthn3ZqgA9O7VEwGHgmIJbqhbghbCScnhkIRasxBAGjrlbIIipGfXgAF4rAIsCVmpoW/7dZ4F%2BMOq5OmmKj7wjn4pgiIh/JgAa0wnX%2Bzw4AFY%2BFwAGxd/rojjY1qYAhiFiNgEECD8vXtDFzdSY/puz2qLAAMwUtiYjZbvM3qmYadcmvxObxxb%2BzjbK1nuo6i5rV5WhbCt/%2BXCLzdb/yHS7riQqhUI0NSNLYojkokB6Xh6Xr9CItgNgQCArBumCbnWDA1D6DCoMgKzARBAbaD6SEUoQfq%2BhmBBZpUTAAHRNoxe5lOijFweuZg1KheABskqCOt6DB9IJTR0aghLeiEqhkcotgKFGDbVOilTtAgEYIFUAZpgyqCkFxXqbm0YRyeRiksFGqBHuMLilgQlQzJ86KqAARs4wa2Fu2G4aJBFEcQnHnni64qgyTKqMy/JGjpqhSYm%2Bx4OgBIEEwwAiKIAbIAgIgsE23osClLD6iETDoJ5DZtKJwWmniRmtKwQqqJuEIhS1wEQG0VqtKoIA3neBBosuL6ch15IQHyfWtMNw6jWN%2BIgigojWlofhDAQIwgIIY7tBAAAss1rVoVImgt9UrnBnJLWg9ZxOtYAyJ2mgsI9Z0Xpd7UNUo/pNMg41wa1E27HgzxskuoPrXOHRuvw/B4LN2JXfiQOqJNlJUGDbqY1DFYujw6i8PwVCI/N503St90nUtO0EHth1U5oaMfoNXBdjweADuzVADs8eAAFTQ%2B0hME86DDPsjF2ru112baMt2rZoD1PS9b0Il9n3pBYmtSGijDSJ2UikCw0gmEbqDSErRO8EMUESITsi0EbBCm7retNiAnYmPrUj7UbJtSGbpAW1IRuCCA3su4HuukHAsAwIgy3ZHgDAMuQlBoMnqfECAwAABxcKQ244Qy4cQG5rukG5CgOM40hO6QmdbFcADyLAMHX0ekFgiRsKnlf4CE%2Bh4Lo4ddySej1pIUgN9UmAMJXwR4GE9cx8wbAoHDvCMHgbnh5AeuoMkkmEtIAC0LeyKoZ/DCKwDUlvPBcEwYd25ItB6wvUiG8blch8Sedexn17PtVQwBkD/Tzoxb8EBcCEGAnIegqhFRZwZA7D%2ByDH7O1dmid2ntvZfz9qQFevZOyMU7LQTEXB9q0FkJiAAnI7EwshOy/y7iHMOEdSBRzNnrOOicVrJHrOnCAmdkgpwZHQUgmB8AGCke0JwyRV6fwNv7P%2B0hEGqHaIQbSACgEgLARA1QUCuDYOjrg0gIZyqSLUoQo2K9ZD7UYvtAumJOyAK4CYXsed6G9l7GwoOHChBcJ4W7UgHsvY%2B1kGo9h0gzG8JUVIUxATzZxO4TgvWuhiBNCkiAfaQA%3D%3D%3D)
[wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ePwWnCDFQcFR3QqH)

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T, int col>
using row_templ = std::array<T,col>;

template<typename T, int col, template <typename,int> typename U = row_templ>
using mat_templ = std::vector<U<T,col>>;

int main()
{
    constexpr int numVertex = 30;
    constexpr int numEdge = 30;
    constexpr int numCol = numVertex;
    int numRow = numEdge;
    using row_t = row_templ<int, numCol>; // alias to the explicit class template specialization
    using mat_t = mat_templ<int, numCol>;
    auto make_mat = [&](){ return mat_t(numRow); }; // define a maker if lazy

    mat_t my_mat(numRow);
    mat_t my_mat2 = make_mat(); // or just use our maker
    // Due to that default allocator uses value initialization, a.k.a T().
    // At this point, all positions are value init to int(), which is zero,
    // from value init of array<int, col>() by the default allocator.
    // numVertex x numEdge is one solid contaguous chunk and now ready to roll.

    // range for
    for (row_t r : my_mat) {
        for (int n : r) {
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << n;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // classic for
    for (int i = 0; i < numRow; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCol; ++j) {
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << (my_mat2[i][j] = i*numRow + numCol);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

}
```